# Capacitor Android fails to fetch from api

Tags: android-studio, ionic-framework, mobile, fetch, capacitor

I'm trying to port my webapp to android by using capacitor.
I've got all but one part figured out.

Whenever I wanna get something from the databaser/server, i'm using fetch. And that works great in the browser - both on desktop and mobile.
But when I run the app through Android Studio, the fetch just fails with this error message

> E/Capacitor/Console: File: http://localhost/ - Line 0 - Msg: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

On the same device, but in the browser it works just fine.

I've tried adding a *network-security-config.xml* with the following

```
<network-security-config>
    <network-security-config>
        <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
            <domain includeSubdomains="true">http://5e4ce8849526.ngrok.io</domain>
        </domain-config>
    </network-security-config>
</network-security-config>
```

I've seen other people converting to HTTPS, but I couldn't get that to work either. This is for at school project due in a few days, so a timeconsuming process is not what I need.

Can it be caused by ngrok?

This is the fetch function running on load

```
let url = ' http://5e4ce8849526.ngrok.io'

function autoLogin(cb) {

    let key = localStorage.getItem('userToken');
    if(key == null || key == '') {
        
        return 'No key stored';
    
    } else {
    fetch(url + '/informatik/readingapp/restapi/api/users/login.php', {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
                        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + key
                    },
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((data) => {

            console.log(data)

            switch(data.message) {
                case 'Password not verified':
                    presentAlert('Forkert kodeord', 'Har du skrevet dit kodeord rigtigt?')
                    break;

                case 'Password verified':
                    nav.push('nav-home')

                    let tk = data.jwt.token
                    let usnm = data.username
                    let usid = data.id

                    cb(tk, usnm, usid);
                    break;

                case 'No login data': 
                    presentToastHome('Intet gemt login, desværre :(')
                    break;
            }
        })
    }
}
```

I would appreciate any help :)

Comment: Check this URL "https://www.joshmorony.com/an-introduction-to-http-requests-fetching-data-in-ionic/" use `HttpClient` angular functionality instead of fetch on-call API. it's working in android, ios and browser also. you just need to add `HttpClientModule` in "imports: [HttpClientModule]" in "app.module.ts"

Comment: I should have mentioned this in the post, but I don't use angular. I'm using native javascript unfortunately

Comment: Oh Okay sorry for that. Try to add `let fetch:any` and check.

Comment: @Jakrox did you get a solution for this?  I am still experiencing the same issues

Answer (score 2):

try to add
`<Application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">`

in the AndroidManifest.xml of your app.

Since Api29 this is needed to do http request on android.